# What type of storage does an iPod classic use?

Tags: storage, ipod-classic

I am interested to know if a newer generation iPod classic uses a standard hard drive or flash memory. Do you know what type of memory an iPod classic uses?

Comment: Edited the question to make it *marginally* quicker to type than to visit `Apple.com/ipod` and click `Classic` then `Specs`.

Answer (score 8):

The [specs page for the iPod Classic](http://www.apple.com/ipodclassic/specs.html) says "hard drive". That's a mechanical drive with a set of spinning platters and read/write heads.

And [here's a replacement part for the drive in the unit](http://www.powerbookmedic.com/iPod-Classic-160GB-Hard-Drive-HS161JQ-655-1398D-p-17277.html). The compatibility list on that page lists:

- iPod 6th Gen 160GB
- iPod 7th Gen 160GB

And here's a video that gives some details on the Samsung drive in the unit: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mB3xjIIKcU

Comment: You are *far* too kind ;)

Comment: Go big or go home, I say. :)

Comment: No, really *far too kind*

Answer (score 1):

All generations of the iPod classic use a hard-drive for storage. That's what the [Apple's tech specs](http://www.apple.com/ipodclassic/specs.html) specify, as well as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Classic).

Answer (score 1):

The [iPod Classic Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Classic#Models) use 'mechanical' **hard drive [platters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard-disk_platter)**. That is the round disk that also hard disk drives have. You notice this by the **noise** they make.

Answer (score 0):

[Capacity](http://www.apple.com/ipodclassic/specs.html):

```
160GB hard drive*
```

*1GB = 1 billion bytes; actual formatted capacity less.

Answer (score -1):

It uses an old hard drive with magnetic discs.